# Create a Grid Art in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a clickable grid.

```
When the user clicks a grid
Then fill that box with a chosen color
And continue filling cells
But if user clicks mouse
Then stop filling cells

When the user inputs grid dimensions
Then create the grid cells
```

I have the basic grid structure, but it appears and then disappears.

```js
function makeGrid() {
  var heights = document.getElementById("inputHeight").value;
  var widths = document.getElementById("inputWidth").value;
  for (var i=0; i<heights; i++){
    for (var j=0; j<heights; j++){
      var x = document.createElement("CANVAS");
      var ctx = x.getContext("2d");
      //stroke(0);
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.fillRect(63*heights, 63*widths, 63, 63);
      document.body.appendChild(x);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Monoton;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
    margin: 1em 0 0.25em;
}

h2:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

table,
tr,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

tr {
    height: 20px;
}

td {
    width: 20px;
}

input[type=number] {
    width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
    <title>Clickable Grid!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Clickable Grid</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1">
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit" value= "submit" onClick = "makeGrid()">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas"></table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your submit button is triggering a refresh. You need to stop the refresh.

Comment: i didn't see canvas element in your html file how can you render the result? something like this <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

Comment: @JesseJay he is creating the canvas element in `makeGrid()` and appending it to the body.

Answer (score 0):

The submit event is triggering a refresh. You need to tap into the `submit` event and prevent its default action.

In addition, you have an off-by-one error, for grid width, in `makeGrid()`, because you are using `height` value for both loops. The grid doesn't appear as you want because the logic needs modification (outside the scope of this question):

```js
function makeGrid(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var heights = document.getElementById("inputHeight").value;
  var widths = document.getElementById("inputWidth").value;
  for (var i=0; i<heights; i++){
    for (var j=0; j<widths; j++){
      var x = document.createElement("CANVAS");
      var ctx = x.getContext("2d");
      //stroke(0);
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.fillRect(63*heights, 63*widths, 63, 63);
      document.body.appendChild(x);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Monoton;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
    margin: 1em 0 0.25em;
}

h2:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

table,
tr,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

tr {
    height: 20px;
}

td {
    width: 20px;
}

input[type=number] {
    width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
    <title>Clickable Grid!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Clickable Grid</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker" onsubmit="makeGrid(event)">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1">
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit" value= "submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas"></table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the j loop for a typo . Next I will be working on clicking the grid and filling them with a color of user choice.Could you provide me with any pointers/tips on how to go about it (probably event listener on mouse click? )

Comment: Awesome, if you need help, feel free to ping me

Comment: I modified the code a little to use HTML tables instead of canvas. Now I want to click individual cells in the table and fill color of choice (user input). Edited the code above

Comment: When you create the `td`, add an `onclick` handler that will set the `td`s `backgroundColor` style to the color-picker's value.

Comment: Create another question, after your attempt, I will try to help

Comment: thanks a ton! I think I have done it and with alert I verified the color value getting assigned to 'td' . But not sure if I did the correct way , I will create another question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52636590/10447126 -- New question